# Парсинг jquery

Tags: jquery, синтаксический-анализ

Есть некий список созданный с помощью плагина jqGrid для jq, хочу сделать так чтобы при клике на один из вариантов в списке была возможность его отредактировать в другой форме. Все бы хорошо, только не получаеться нормально получить данные из панели чтобы отправить их в форму для редактирования. 
У jqGrid такая вот html структура:

```
<tr id="1">
  <td title="имя"></td>
  <td title="ссылка"></td>
</tr>
```

нужно выдрать по очереди все td, наворотил вот такое:

```
    test = $('tr[id="'+id+'"]').find( 'td' ).text();
    alert(test);
```

так вот получаеться что дергаються все td сразу в одну переменную :(

В живую посмотреть на создаваемую таблицу можно тут - http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 2):

Если вы точно знаете, что ячеек будет всегда две, то напишите так

```
test = $('tr[id="'+id+'"]').find( 'td' );
name = test[0].text();
link = test[1].text();
```

если ячеек может быть сколько угодно, то нужно использовать test.each(function(){}) или цикл

```
for (i=0;i<test.length;i++) {test[i].text()}
```

Comment: Не получаеться, alert вообще не срабатывает.

Comment: Только не `test[i]`, а `test.eq(i)` - первый вариант возвращает элемент, а второй - объект jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. Не дергает только ссылку, хотя структура там такая же, не подскажите в чем может быть дело и как с этим справиться ?

Comment: для ссылки нужно не text() применять, а html()